# Handling saves and redirects asynchronously in node js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node.js and am just trying to understand the asynchronous nature of how this stuff works.
Ok this is a very simple form submission.The model looks like the below:-

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var PostSchema=new Schema({
title:{type:String,required:true},
    post:String,
});
var PostModel=mongoose.model('blogpost',PostSchema);
module.exports=PostModel;
```

and then the route handler is as below:-

```
app.post("/submitpost",function(req,res){
        var title=req.body.title;
        var post=req.body.post;
        var thepost=new PostModel({title:title,post:post});
        thepost.save(function(err,data){
            if(err)throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })
    console.log("title is "+title);
    console.log("post is "+post);
    res.send("saved");
  });
```

Now suppose the validation fails during "thepost.save(callback)" , i would want to show an error page rather than "saved" . How would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the rendering of the response into the callback:

```javascript
app.post("/submitpost",function(req,res){
        var title=req.body.title;
        var post=req.body.post;
        var thepost=new PostModel({title:title,post:post});
        thepost.save(function(err,data){
            if(err) {
              res.render('errorPage');
            } else {
              console.log(data);
              console.log("title is "+title);
              console.log("post is "+post);
              res.send("saved");
            }
        })
  });
```

Comment: sometimes one does end up asking weird questions :-).. thanks